# A troubling doubling

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, science

#### The answers to all the clues below are rhyming doublets.

(Except there is one rhyming triplet, which is marked.)

So if I say:

> Hirsuite stone fruit

you reply:

> **Hairy cherry**

Or if I say:

> Friendly—but not romantic—proctological exam

you reply:

> **Platonic colonic**

There are four sets of these clues below.  Your goals are to:

1. **Figure out each rhyming couplet.**
2. **Discover the hidden word(s) in each set of answers.**
3. **Explain how the 4 hidden word(s) are related to one another.**

**Note**: The rhymes are generally decent, but perhaps not unimpeachable.  I tried.

---

#### Set 1

> 1. Didn’t really make a difference
> 2. Hanging someone, most commonly
> 3. Motionless pharmaceutical
> 4. Enter verification code for new version of software
> 5. Beakers, flasks, pipettor, balance, Bunsen burner, safety goggles, etc.
> 6. What a lidocaine injection often does

#### Set 2

> 1. Obese rodent
> 2. Taste failure
> 3. Begin separated
> 4. Approach equipment
> 5. Leave before the FBI kicks in the door

#### Set 3

> 1. Prepared a citrus beverage
> 2. It is used to draw the Penguins' or Sharks' logos on the ice
> 3. One who will never be promoted to general
> 4. A peppy withdrawal from battle
> 5. Exemplary unagi

#### Set 4

> 1. Cheerful Twist
> 2. The yellow fruits belonging to the grandmother of Derek Jeter’s fiancée (triplet)
> 3. A breathtaking building destruction
> 4. It’s not present in a theater after an emotional performance
> 5. Google Images SafeSearch does this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set 1

Didn’t really make a difference

> Lacked Impact

Hanging someone, most commonly

> Noose Use

Motionless pharmaceutical

> Still Pill

Enter verification code for new version of software

> Authenticate Update

Beakers, flasks, pipettor, balance, Bunsen burner, safety goggles, etc.

> Laboratory Inventory

What a lidocaine injection often does

> Numbs Gums

Set 2

Obese rodent

> Fat Rat

Taste failure

> Eat Defeat

Begin separated

> Start Apart

Approach equipment

> Near Gear

Leave before the FBI kicks in the door

> Evade Raid

Set 3

Prepared a citrus beverage

> Made (Lemon)Ade

It is used to draw the Penguins' or Sharks' logos on the ice

> Rink Ink

One who will never be promoted to general

> Eternal Colonel

A peppy withdrawal from battle

> Upbeat Retreat

Exemplary unagi

> Ideal Eel

Set 4

Cheerful Twist

> Jolly Oli

The yellow fruits belonging to the grandmother of Derek Jeter’s fiancée (triplet)

> Hannah's Nanna's Bananas

A breathtaking building destruction

> Amazing Razing

It’s not present in a theater after an emotional performance

> Dry Eye

Google Images SafeSearch does this

> Excludes Nudes

What links each set is:

> The initial letters of each answer, so we get
>  Set 1:[LINUS PAULING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Pauling)
>  Set 2:[FRED SANGER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Sanger)
>  Set 3:[MARIE CURIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Curie)
>  Set 4:[JOHN BARDEEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Bardeen)

And they are all:

> People who have won Nobel Prizes Twice

With thanks to **Deusovi**, **Lighthart**, **whrrgarbl** and especially **Wesley Situ**

Comment: "Peppy withdrawal" -> "Upbeat Retreat"?

Comment: "Hanging someone..." → "Noose use"

Comment: Hehehe...I knew there would be some valid but unintended answers...didn't expect that rot13(oybpxf pbpxf) one though!

Comment: @GordonK The third and fifth of Set 4 are not the intended ones as of now.

Comment: @GordonK (et al) Nicely done! The very first clue is not quite right. You previously had the correct second word, but not the correct first word.

Comment: @DanRussell Ok now?